# Hide some item in main menu , according to the example image

Tags: android, menu, hide

I bought a source code from Codecanyon. I want to hide  or invisible some item and all  its children from menu . according to the image( [example menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkbzC.png)), for example, hide  the item " share" ...as, the item disappeared
please explain simple for a beginner. Already, You were in the beginning too...
link attached image: http://s5.picofile.com/file/8362836676/aY741_1_.png

Best regards.

Comment: Please provide some related code...

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would approach that, hopefully it helps you.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_Settings).setVisible(false);
    return true;
}
```